# Pandas: How to One Hot Encode Categorical features

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, classification, random-forest, one-hot-encoding

I have a data-frame `X` which has two categorical features and 41 numerical features. So `X` has total of 43 features.

Now, I would like to convert the categorical features into numerical levels so they can be used in `RandomForest` Classifier.

I have done following, where `0` and `1` indicate location of categorical features:

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.read_csv("train.csv")

F1 = pd.get_dummies(X.iloc[:, 0])

F2 = pd.get_dummies(X.iloc[:, 1])
```

Then, I concatenate these two data-frames:

```
Xnew = pd.concat([F1, F2, X.ix[:, 2:]])
```

Now, `Xnew` has 63 features (`F1` has 18 and `F2` has 4 features, remaining 41 are from `X`)

Is this correct? Is there a better way of doing the same thing? Do I need to drop the first column from `F1` and `F2` to avoid collinearity?

Comment: I see the issue, please ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com/,

Comment: Thanks. Posted here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232541/pandas-how-to-one-hot-encode-categorical-features

Answer (score 0):

Since `F1` has 18 *levels* (not features) and F2 has 4, your result looks correct.

To avoid collinearity, you should better drop one of the columns (for each F1 and F2). Not necessarily the first column. Typically you drop the column with the most common level.

Why the one with the most common level? Think about feature importance. If you drop one column, it has no chance to get its importance estimated. This level (the one you dropped) is like your "base level". Only deviations from the base level can be marked as important or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if I understand correctly, F1 will be a sparse matrix of 1s and 0s. In that case, I need to drop the column with maximum sum. For example, 3rd column has more 1s compared to others, then I need to drop the 3rd column. And do the same for F2. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. This is what I meant.

Comment: Ok. But the approach I took to create F1 and F2 is correct? I mean, is there any an easier/better way to create such features? For example, if I have, let's say 50 categorical features, then what would be the ideal way?